# In Woocommerce, how to add custom attribute total on cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a diamond jewellery e-commerce website using Woocommerce.

I want to add custom attributes - Gold Weight and Diamond Carats for all the products.

My question is:
1. How to show these custom attributes as columns on cart page?
2. How to show total of gold weight and diamond carats on cart page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the first task try using this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-show-attributes/

For second task try following code:

```php
function my_attribute_sum () {
    $total = array();
    $runningSum = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $quantity =  $cart_item['quantity'];
        if(!empty($product)){
            $product_attr = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_my_attribute' );
            $product_quantity = $product->get_attribute( 'quantity' );
            $runningSum = $product_attr * $quantity;
            $total[] = $runningSum;
        }
    }
echo 'Total sum is: ' . array_sum ($total);
}
add_action ('woocommerce_after_cart_table', 'my_attribute_sum');
```

Swap `pa_my_attribute` with appropriate name. I am not sure this will work for variable products but this works for sure for simple products.

Comment: @ashish-bafna, what's the purpose of asking questions here and not bothering to check the answer?